# How to import global less mixin so it can be used in any components?

Tags: webpack, less, less-mixins

I was using webpack `extract-text-plugin` with the following code, and got the error: `ModuleBuildError: Module build failed: .bg is undefined`. Is there a way to make such way of importing work?

my `index.jsx` file is as below:

```
import 'style-theme-module/less/index.less'
import './style.less'
```

my style-theme-module/less/index.less is:

```
.bg{
   color: white
}
```

my style.less is:

```
.app{
   .bg()
}
```